# System hangs on shutdown if Windows network drive in fstab

Tags: 10.04, network-manager, samba, shutdown, cifs

I added a Windows network drive (accessed using WiFi) in my fstab about a month ago:

```
//Server/Location/foo/bar /media/myNetworkDrive/ cifs auto,iocharset=utf8,uid=umang,credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 0 0
```

and it works perfectly well, except it takes about a full minute for the system to shutdown. I have tried the solutions posted on [the help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently), the [team wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and on [this blog](http://whereofwecannotspeak.wordpress.com/2007/12/25/unmount-samba-filesystems-before-shutdown-or-reboot/). One of them worked for a few shutdowns but then the system went back to taking a minute to shutdown again.

**EDIT:** I'd like a *working* working around for this problem. Currently, I have a script that unmounts (password required for super-user priviledges) and then shuts down the computer, but I'd like to be able to shutdown the usual way and have it shutdown as fast.

Comment: In my case, it is writing to the file system stalling that causes the problem. Check if the same is true in your case.

Comment: I no longer have this set up, so I don't need to fix it (and cannot check if your solution works either). Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This is a well known bug :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/211631?comments=all

It's one of those thankfully-rare, but nonetheless embarrassing, high impact, over-two-years-old bugs that negatively impact Ubuntu's sheen.

It should only affect WIFI connections, but I don't see any detail about that in your question.  If you're experiencing this over a wired connection then something else is in play here.

Until Network Manager is fixed (it shuts down wifi connections too quickly - before any of the init scripts are triggered), the only feasible workaround I could find is to use AutoFS.

Paraphrased from http://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs

```
sudo apt-get install autofs
```

Create /etc/auto.cifs with these file contents :

```
#!/bin/bash
# $Id$
# This file must be executable to work! chmod 755!
key="$1"
# Note: create a cred file for each windows/Samba-Server in your network
#       which requires password authentification.  The file should contain
#       exactly two lines:
#          username=user
#          password=*****
#       Please don't use blank spaces to separate the equal sign from the
#       user account name or password.
credfile="/etc/auto.smb.$key"
# Note: Use cifs instead of smbfs:
mountopts="-fstype=cifs,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=user,gid=users"
smbclientopts=""
for P in /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin
do
        if [ -x $P/smbclient ]
        then
                SMBCLIENT=$P/smbclient
                break
        fi
done
[ -x $SMBCLIENT ] || exit 1
if [ -e "$credfile" ]
then
        mountopts=$mountopts",credentials=$credfile"
        smbclientopts="-A "$credfile
else
        smbclientopts="-N"
fi
$SMBCLIENT $smbclientopts -gL $key 2>/dev/null \
   | awk -v key="$key" -v opts="$mountopts" -F'|' -- '
        BEGIN   { ORS=""; first=1 }
    /Disk/  { if (first) { print opts; first=0 };
          gsub(/ /, "\\ ", $2);
          sub(/\$/, "\\$", $2);
          print " \\\n\t /" $2, "://" key "/" $2 }
        END     { if (!first) print "\n"; else exit 1 }
        '
```

**(edit the mountops line to reflect your real user name)**

Make it exectuable with `sudo chmod 755 /etc/auto.cifs`

Then add this line to your /etc/auto.master, at the bottom :

```
/smb /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=60 --ghost
```

Finally, restart autofs with this line (or a reboot would work, of course) :

```
sudo service autofs restart
```

And you should then be able to open nautilus to /smb/server/share (or `ls -l /smb/Server/Share`)

Shutdown, suspend, hibernate should all be seamless.

If you use passwords to connect to your shares, you have to add another file in /etc/ for each server you connect to, with username and password specified.  Do a "man autofs" for more detail on that, but here's the gist :

You need one credentials file for each password-protected share that you're connecting to.  In your case, your server is called "Server", so create the relevant file with `gksudo gedit /etc/auto.smb.Server`.  Then put this into that file :

```
username=myusername
password=mypassword
```

(obviously editing the fields as required).

Then you'll need to make sure that this file is only readable by root with `sudo chmod 600 /etc/auto.smb.Server`.

Then restart autofs as above and try browsing /smb/Server - you should see a list of your shares.

If you connect using an IP address, you'll need to repeat this process for /etc/auto.smb.192.168.1.10 or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question and mentioned WiFi there. I will not and cannot access that network for a couple weeks. I shall try your solution and accept/comment on this answer when I can.

Comment: I wasn't able to do it exactly the way you suggested, but when I did something similar to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1494525 it still takes quite a while to shutdown/restart.

Comment: That's disappointing.  Autofs shouldn't trigger this bug at all.  I have three samba shares specified, I use one of those every minute of every day, but my shutdown is near-instant (certainly never longer than 10 seconds).  How's your suspend/resume (if you use it)?

Comment: Suspend/resume is fine, but IIRC it was never troublesome when I had my share in fstab. BTW, I removed the share from my fstab when I started using autofs. I was supposed to do that, right?

Comment: Yep - autofs doesn't use /etc/fstab at all.  Did you specify the timeout option?  If you don't, I think you might still get the CIFS VFS errors.

Comment: I have `/cifs /etc/auto.home --timeout=60 --ghost` in my `auto.master` file and my `auto.home` is: `ShareName -fstype=cifs,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/etc/auto.smb.ShareName ://ShareName/dir`

Comment: Don't think autofs works that way.  As noted above, no need for auto.home.  The install of autofs will give you a generic auto.smb file.  That's a script that maps the drives automatically when you browse to /smb.  If you need credentials, then in your case, you need an additional file called auto.smb.server (where server=your server name or IP address).  I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Alright, I cannot seem to get your solution to work. I've followed your  answer carefully (double checked) and nothing shows up in `/smb/` after I restart autofs. So I want to check, by server you mean what I have called `ShareName` in my previous comment, right?  I really appreciate your help here, BTW.

Comment: Not quite - in `/smb/` if you've configured it right, you should see `server` listed.  Actually, even that's not quite right - you won't "see" the server listed until you browse to it, so open a terminal and try `ls -al /smb/server`.  The result should be a list of the shares on that server.  Good luck.

Comment: I still can't get it to work using `/etc/auto.smb`. I have followed all your instructions and even checked `ls -al /smb/Server` instead of just `ls -al /smb/` and I get `ls: cannot access /smb/Server/: No such file or directory`. **However**, with the old autofs solution (using auto.home), shutdown works fine if I haven't just used the share (I'd imagine because autofs umounts the share after 60 seconds on inactivity). I would like to get it to work using `auto.smb` though. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: (in the above answer, I did replace `Server` with the appropriate name). Also if you could edit your answer in some small way, I'll up vote it. I can't because I un-up-voted your answer by mistake and need you to edit it before I can vote up again.

Comment: Umang, apologies.  It's been so long since I've used password-protected shares in my house that it looks like I've been selling you a dummy.  I don't think auto.smb actually uses the credential files, as I thought.  I've added the auto.cifs script from the HowToForge article that I originally used some years ago.  Sorry

Comment: Still don't seem to be able to see the share. I've made sure I followed your instructions and still don't find anything in `/smb/Server` and in `/cifs/Server` (whichever one I set in `auto.master`, I've tried both). I've ensured I've got the credential files right (I've even check on vim with `:set list` to make sure there are no hidden spaces). `/var/log/syslog` says things about NetworkManager but that doesn't appear to be relevant. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess the issue is still there, 5 years later?

Comment: Couldn't the 2 minutes try-to-connect-delay be lowered to 1 sec or so?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the fix has been there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1438612: add `ExecStop=/bin/true
KillMode=none` to `/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service` in th `[Head]` section

Answer (score 0):

You should use the guide which shows you how to make an unmount shutdown script and make sure that it's still switch on. Upgrades or updates could theoretically have knocked it off it's perch. Check that your script is in `/etc/rc0.d` and that it's named `S01smb_umount` or similar so it runs as the first order of business.

Otherwise you may end up with it unmounting the samba drive normally (waiting, waiting) and then running your script. Which would do nothing.

Comment: I've got the following link: `/etc/rc0.d/K15umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh`. This does not help though.

Comment: Is K15 enough? Shouldn't it be S01? Have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but I've got `/etc/rc0.d/S01smb_umount.sh -> /etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh` and `/etc/rc6.d/S01smb_umount.sh -> /etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh` and have removed the K15 ones. Still facing this problem, after three restarts.

Comment: Then I don't know, it needs attention from an upstart developer on the platform team, please report bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Win2003 server samba share and following [this guide](http://ubuntulinuxhelp.com/cifs-vfs-shutdown-error-when-using-smbfs/) fixed the problem.